# Suggested edit comment wording issues

Tags: discussion, suggested-edit

I was prompted to approve a [suggested edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/38228) (I think the link should work, sorry if it doesn't).

The edit itself was o.k., and I nearly approved it, but the wording was more of a personal comment to the OP:

> Comment: Just because you don't like something doesn't make you the authority on anything. His sells outweigh your childish words.

**What do I do in this case?**

I'm happy to:

- **Skip**, let someone else decide
- **Improve Edit**, come up with some descriptive wording
- **Reject** / **Reject and Edit**, meaning the suggester won't get the +2

Comment: Personally, I'd reject that.  The anonymous editor is changing dlanod's answer due to their own opinion.

Comment: Hypothesis: it was the author of the series himself who made that edit.

Comment: @SQB Interesting hypothesis. Only thing is that in the comment they said "his sales" etc.

Comment: @Mooz Sure, wouldn't want to make it _too_ obvious :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would have rejected it outright. The comment is insulting and the edit radically changes the meaning of the original post without adding any discernible value. The editor is attempting to exchange dlanoD's opinion for his own.

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, that's inappropriate on the user's part.

I would remove the insulting comment and, given that the other edits are indeed an improvement, go ahead and send them through. Would this be "Improve Edit" or "Reject and Edit" though? Perhaps another user can clarify. Under no circumstances would I approve it as is, though. The body of an answer is an inappropriate venue for running commentary and opinion.

Comment: It would be reject and edit.

Comment: Reject and edit -- thanks!